# How to Implement open multiple authenticated user stream of twitter

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

I am creating Twitter client where I want all my authenticated users stream to be fetched from Twitter and send it to the browser or app.
I am using twitter4j java client library to open stream for one user, I don't know how to open it for all the users. Please help.
I am also trying it using Ruby on Rails.